# How to omit the type attribute in a script element?

Tags: html, jsf, jsf-2.2, script-element

Since a few month the W3C validator is complaining about,

> The `type` attribute is unnecessary for JavaScript resources.

for HTML5 ([example](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fshowcase.omnifaces.org%2F)).

Unfortunately JSF 2.2 always writes the attribute.
`<script type="text/javascript">`

Offers JSF a way to suppress the `type` attribute for the `script` tag?